# rails 3 searchlogic & fckeditor gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fckeditor, searchlogic

I  used  searchlogic and fckedtior plugin rails 2x application currently i am converting that rails 2x application into rails 3x application this two gem not working in rails 3x can any one tell me any other related gem which support rails 3x or how to fix these error

for fckedtior   i am getting the following error

```
Started GET "/fckeditor/command?Command=GetFoldersAndFiles&Type=Image&CurrentFolder=%2F&uuid=1409200403319" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 10:03:23 +0530

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'command' could not be found for FckeditorController):
```

searchlogic gem can't installed

Thanks in Advance